# Whitespace gaps between divs in email

Tags: html, email, outlook

I've been working on this for hours and I have no idea what is going on.

I am sending a html email and I get a big white gap between the bottom divs.

works fine in browser, just showing up weird in email. 'outlook'

Whats going on here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body alink="#EE0000" link="#0000EE" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" vlink="#551A8B">
  <div style="background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">
    <div style="background-color: white;">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with removing white spaces from your code in between html tags and elements.

Comment: I tried with the code minimized. no dice.

Comment: When you send HTML email your design should be in table format so convert your design into <table> format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to convert your design into `<table>` format.Most of email client support html email in  format and not in `<div>`.

While moving design into `<table>` form remember to use `<span>` tags instead of `<p>` tags.

**Here is an example email template**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```